# Broken include paths for cython with anaconda on windows

Tags: anaconda, cython, include-path, cythonize

I am having trouble with cython and anaconda.

For the sake of argument, let's assume I want to use a header file that is part of `libxml2`: `xmlversion.h`

I have installed the package `libxml2` with anaconda in my build environment, but `cythonize` complains that it cannot find the header file.

After investigating further, I found that the headers for libxml are linked in the folder:

```
C:\Miniconda3\envs\build-env\Library\include\libxml
```

That path is not automatically added to the build command however (see below). Instead, the following path gets added twice:

```
C:\Miniconda3\envs\build-env\include
```

The build command generated by `cythonize -3 -a -i xmltest.pyx` on my machine is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Miniconda3\envs\build-env\lib\site-packages\lxml\includes -IC:\Miniconda3\envs\build-env\include -IC:\Miniconda3\envs\build-env\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" "/TcC:\Users\My User\Documents\my_proj\xmltest.c" "/FoC:\Users\My User\Documents\my_proj\tmpy_5rengr\Release\Users\My User\Documents\my_proj\xmltest.obj"
xmltest.c
C:\Users\My User\Documents\my_proj\xmltest.c(621): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

---

**Note 1:** Question was modified after merv's comment

Comment: I can't replicate.  That is, I also have an env (call it `myenv`) with `libxml2` and it definitely has all the header files in `envs/myenv/include/libxml2/libxml/`, including `xmlversion.h`.  But, I'm not on Windows, so take it FWIW.

Comment: @merv Thanks for taking the time to investigate. I found that the headers do get linked after all to the environment, to `build-env\Library\include`. cython however only gets `build-env\include` passed as include path. That however gets passed twice! (See details in updated OP.)